# jQuery / JavaScript Table Paginator

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-pagination

I've looking almost everywhere for a jQuery/JavaScript table paginator. I found a few but were just too much for what I intended to use it for. All I need is a simple jquery plugin to help paginate html table. `Datatables` are just too much for what i want. Any help or reference will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or this: http://cssglobe.com/post/9801/easy-paginate-jquery-plugin-for-pagination

Answer (score 1):

You can try this http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-pagination